# Usage of 韓服 and チマチョゴリ

Tags: word-choice, loanwords

[韓服](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%93%E6%9C%8D) literally translates as [hanbok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbok) (which in turn literally translates as Korean clothing), and [チマチョゴリ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%9E%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA) literally translates as [chima jeogori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chima_jeogori), which in turn literally translates as a chima skirt plus a jeogori top, but when do Japanese-speakers use 韓服, and when do they use チマチョゴリ?

A native speaker of Japanese said that チマチョゴリ is more commonly used than 韓服. Is that true? I suspect that in English, hanbok is more commonly used than chima jeogori, based on personal experience plus google hits.

In Japanese, would you say "She wore a hanbok" using 韓服, or チマチョゴリ? If the latter, would a man wearing a hanbok be described as wearing a パジチョゴリ (baji jeogori)?

I'm mainly concerned with what's used in normal conversation, rather than technical correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I have never seen 韓服, although its meaning is instantly understandable if presented in kanji.

チマチョゴリ is a specific term that refers to a certain Korean outfit for women, not Korean clothes in general. I believe most native Japanese speakers are familiar with this word. I learnt this word at middle school, and it can be the only word an ordinary Japanese people knows about Korean dresses.

I didn't know what English *hanbok* refers to, either, but if you want to talk about traditional Korean clothing in general including that for males, how about 韓国の(民族)衣装?